# How to quantify similarity between to plots with similar pattern?

Tags: r

I compared the value of these two plots, as you can see, although their values are different, they have similar pattern. In othe words, the ordering of each gene in each group is important. How can I quantify this similarity?

[image]

Here is `df`

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Gene = c("Gene 1", "Gene 2", "Gene 3", "Gene 4", 
"Gene 5", "Gene 6", "Gene 7", "Gene 8", "Gene 9", "Gene 10", 
"Gene 11", "Gene 12", "Gene 13", "Gene 14", "Gene 15", "Gene 16", 
"Gene 1", "Gene 2", "Gene 3", "Gene 4", "Gene 5", "Gene 6", "Gene 7", 
"Gene 8", "Gene 9", "Gene 10", "Gene 11", "Gene 12", "Gene 13", 
"Gene 14", "Gene 15", "Gene 16"), Percent = c(2.6, 15.1, 2.3, 
2.3, 3, 2.1, 3.6, 3.8, 9.2, 3.7, 7.2, 1.8, 3.2, 4.1, 7.2, 2.6, 
1.4, 8.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.7, 1.5, 3, 2.3, 4.6, 2.2, 3.6, 1.1, 1.5, 
2, 2.5, 1), Study = c("PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", 
"PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", 
"PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "PCAWG", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", 
"TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", 
"TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA", "TCGA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

Comment: If you are just interested in `the order`, you can assign an index position to each Gene in both studies. A comparison can then be a simple subtraction (assuming each Gene at same [ordered] position would yield a `0` per Gene) and then sum it (~ small total ~ similar order). If it is the `shape`, you could normalise it (or also work with the delta). Again a gene-wise comparison will give you a "matching" value. If you do not want to work with a total sum, you can determine the share of matches between different thresholds.

Answer (score 2):

You could compare gene `rank`s.

```
df[with(df, order(Study, Gene)), ] |>
  with(by(Percent, Study, rank)) |> simplify2array()
#       PCAWG TCGA
#  [1,]   5.5  4.5
#  [2,]  10.0 10.0
#  [3,]  13.5 14.0
#  [4,]   1.0  2.0
#  [5,]   8.0  6.5
#  [6,]  12.0  9.0
#  [7,]  13.5 12.0
#  [8,]   5.5  1.0
#  [9,]  16.0 16.0
# [10,]   3.5  4.5
# [11,]   3.5  3.0
# [12,]   7.0  8.0
# [13,]   2.0  6.5
# [14,]   9.0 13.0
# [15,]  11.0 11.0
# [16,]  15.0 15.0
```

E.g. by squared row differences and take the `mean`, which will give you sth like a mean squared error.

```
df[with(df, order(Study, Gene)), ] |>
  with(by(Percent, Study, rank)) |> simplify2array() |> 
  matrixStats::rowDiffs() |> base::`^`(2) |> mean()
# [1] 4.65625
```

Answer (score 2):

An obvious choice would be to examine the correlation between percentages in matched genes using `cor.test`

```r
cor.test(df$Percent[df$Study == "PCAWG"], df$Percent[df$Study == "TCGA"])
#> 
#>  Pearson's product-moment correlation
#> 
#> data:  df$Percent[df$Study == "PCAWG"] and df$Percent[df$Study == "TCGA"]
#> t = 13.648, df = 14, p-value = 1.764e-09
#> alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.8980195 0.9878583
#> sample estimates:
#>       cor 
#> 0.9644133
```

This shows a correlation of 96.4%, which is indeed an extremely strong correlation.